# How to solve this equation $\mathbb{P}\{ W_1 > 2 | W_4 = 4\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, wiener-measure

> Assume that $W_t$ is a standard Wiener (Brownian motion) process. Calculate:
>
> $$\mathbb{P} \{ W_1 > 2 | W_4 = 4 \}$$

This my way of solving this problem but I am not sure is it right:
<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7rEO.png)</sup>

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}\{ W_1 > 2 | W_4 = 4\} \\
&= \mathbb{P}\{ W_0 > 0 | W_3 = 2\}
= \mathbb{P}\{ W_3 = 2 \} \\
&= \mathbb{P}\{ N(0, 3) > 2 \}
= \mathbb{P}\{ \sqrt{3} \cdot N(0, 1) > 2 \}
= \mathbb{P}\left\{ N(0, 1) > \tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right\} \\
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\left\{ N(0, 1) \leq \tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right\}
= 1 - \Phi\left(\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(W_4=4)=0$, so you're conditioning on a null event and $\mathbb{P}(W_1 > 2 | W_4=4)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Also, note the very first step is not correct. You may first try to show that $\tilde{W}_t = W_t - \frac{t}{4} W_4$ is a gaussian process independent of $W_4$. (This is called a [Brownian bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge).) Using this, you can write $$\mathbb{P}\{W_1>2|W_4=4\}=\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{W}_1>1|W_4=4\}=\mathbb{P}\{\tilde{W}_1>1\}.$$ The last one is not hard to compute by writing $\tilde{W}_t=(1-\frac{t}{4})W_t - \frac{t}{4}(W_4-W_t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula: W(s)|W(t) = a ~ (s/t * a; s (1-s/t))

P{W1>2|W4=4} =

P(N(1/4 * 4, 1 (1 - 1/4)) =

P(N(1, 3/4) > 2) =

1 - P(N(1, 3/4) <=

1 - P(N(0, 3/4) <= 1) =

1 - P(sqrt(3/4) N(0, 1) <= 1) =

1 - P(N(0, 1) <= 2/sqrt3) =

1 - Φ(2/sqrt3)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same answer with a slightly different approach. There are also some notable issues in your calculation; note that $\mathbb{P}(W_3=2)=0$.

We have $W_4|W_1\sim \mathcal{N}(W_1,3)$ while $W_1\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Using Baye's theorem we have $$f_{W_1|W_4}(x|y)=\frac{f_{W_4|W_1}(y|x)f_{W_1}(x)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{W_4|W_1}(y|x)f_{W_1}(x)\mathrm{d}x}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\pi}} \exp \Bigg\{-\frac{2}{3}\left(x-\frac{y}{4}\right)^{2}\Bigg\}$$
Evidently $W_1|W_4\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{W_4}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)$ so that $$\mathbb{P}\left(W_1>2|W_4=4\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z>\frac{2-1}{\sqrt{3}/2}\right)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$